# Does CAS 4.0.1 support OAuth Grant Type "Implicit"?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, cas

Does CAS currently (4.0.x) support any other grant type than "Authorization Code"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it supports only the Authorization Code grant as documented here: http://jasig.github.io/cas/4.0.x/protocol/OAuth-Protocol.html and as is shown in the code here: https://github.com/Jasig/cas/tree/master/cas-server-support-oauth/src/main/java/org/jasig/cas/support/oauth/web It does not even parse/interpret the `response_type` parameter, it defaults to `code` flow.